# How to pass values to function calls in z3 python

Tags: python, function, static, z3, verification

I am using z3 Python to verify the a function logic, to which i am passing a value from main, as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
`stm = Array('stm', IntSort(), IntSort()) #declare an array in main`
#initialize n,f 
n,f = Ints('n f')
stm = Store(stm,n,4) #assign stm[n] = 4
stf = Array('stf', IntSort(), IntSort())#declare another int sort
fact,N = Ints('fact N')
stf = Store(stf,stf[N],stm[n]) # i want to assign N=stm[n]
```

I want  to pass stf[N] to a function : verify(stf[N)) which returns some value
How can i check if N holds the value of 'n' in stf[N]? If i do:

```
s= Solver()
```

s.add(stf[N]==stm[n])

and then call s.check()
I get "SAT"
On doing s.sexpr()
I get:

```
'(declare-fun n () Int)\n(declare-fun stm () (Array Int Int))\n(declare-fun N () Int)\n(declare-fun stf () (Array Int Int))\n(define-funs-rec ( ( Factorial ((x!1 Int)) Int))\n                 ( (ite (<= x!1 1) 1 (* x!1 ((_ Factorial 0) (- x!1 1))))))\n(assert (let ((a!1 (select (store stf N (select (store stm n 4) n)) N)))\n  (= a!1 (select (store stm n 4) n))))\n(assert (let ((a!1 (store (store stf N (select (store stm n 4) n))\n                  N\n                  (select (store (store stm n 4) n 4) n))))\n  (= (select a!1 N) (select (store (store stm n 4) n 4) n))))\n'
```

But the main question whether stf[N] holds 4 is not clear..
Please help

Comment: You want to check the return value of `s.check()`, which tells you whether the problem is satisfiable. If so, you can get a model via `s.model()`.

Comment: That is fine. But i wanted to print the value stf[N], and if it holds 4 or not...how can I simply print like in any other language  ?

Comment: That's the model; it's a list of assignments of values to variables. I think `s.model()[stf[N]]` might also work in Python.

Comment: Your questions is very confusing! What's the variable `fact` for? Please consider submitting after correctly formatting and clarifying.

Comment: s.model()[stf[N]] doesnot work :(